# Neo4J Browser Issue

Tags: graph, browser, neo4j

I am not able to see the graph icon on the Neo4J browser launched from the Desktop application. Does anyone know how to get that button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph icon is not visible if you return the tabular data like you just return a few fields of a node. It's only visible when you return a graph(Nodes/Relationships) in your query. From your screenshot looks like you are returning text `"node"` instead of `node`, Please check your query and make sure you are returning nodes.